# Stuck at boot animation on multiple custom ROMs

Tags: twrp, boot-loop

Just yesterday I thought of having a new ROM installed on my phone and it is not the first time I'm doing it. Though I made a mistake of not taking a backup of the system before flashing the custom ROM.

These are the steps that I followed:

1. Moving to bootloader and rebooting to TWRP recovery
2. Wiping the cache, system, data and dalvik cache
3. Moving to `install` option and installing the CustomROM1.zip from the Internal Storage
4. But the screen is stuck at boot animation
5. Using my laptop I tried to do the following:

5.1. `fastboot erase system` and `fastboot erase recovery`

5.2. Flashed TWRP recovery again using `fastboot flash recover twrp.img`

6. Moved the CustomROM2.zip file in the Internal Storage and tried to flash it using `install` option but resulted in boot animation loop

I even tried to ADB sideload and flash the zip but resulted in the same error.
Currently I'm on **Moto G Play (Harpia)** and the ROMs that I used are

CustomROM1 = Resurrection Remix v. 5.8.3

CustomROM2 = Eelo v. 0.7

Any sort of help to get out of this would be totally appreciable. And thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After much try and waiting I couldn't get any satisfactory result out of it. So ultimately I had to flash the stock firmware. The name of the firmware could be deduced from the command `fastboot getvar all`

https://androidforums.com/threads/bootloader-unlock-back-to-stock-for-motorola-e4-plus-owens.1264881/

This is the link anyone who's facing the same issues can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the integrity of the file you're flashing? I have had some that wouldn't flash and after trying every variable, I re-downloaded the file and it flashed no problem. Also consider: after successfully flashing the ROM, boot back into recovery or to the bootloader before booting the system.

Comment: Yes, I checked the integrity of the custom ROMs twice for both of them. Since both of them were showing same sort of results I couldn't stop myself from thinking that the problem lies within the system and not the software being flashed.